# Python 3.4 Pandas 15.2join function locks pc

Tags: python, join, memory, pandas

I'm loading 6 small csv files with 100krecords, indexed  by a 15 alphanumeric text field using a laptop with an i5 and 8Gig of ram.

I load the files into memory, which shows 9% used. Then I execute a join statement.

```
   Df1.join(df2,df3,df4,df5,df6) # join all tables
```

Yes, it's ugly, but it's what I've been asked to do. The moment it hits the join, memory utilization hits 99% instantly and the mouse and all input locks up. I can hear the disk thrashing but can't get control back. After a few hours  I power cycled the machine, but lost all the work.

I'm missing something obvious. This should just add a few columns and kid know back a couple million rows. I've worked with 10M rows on his machine without problems

And it does the same thing when I'm just join ng a couple tables together. Tables are indexed. I've also tried using merge() and concat().

Advice welcome. I'm new to python and pandas, but was a C programmer back in the dark ages before the one was invented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it might be because of a silly problem. pandas should give you an error message, but your tables are too large for it to realize that they're the wrong types. Here's what I think is going on:

[`DataFrame.join(other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) can only join two tables at once. It's interpreting your `df3` as the `on` parameter, `df4` as the `how` parameter, etc... at least, it's trying to, but somewhere it's not happy with them being large data frames. Obviously, with correct parameters, pandas should be able to join large tables.

Similarly, `pandas.merge()` takes a ***list*** of data frames as input. Here's what I'd do:

`pandas.merge([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6], axis=1)`

Or, at least, that's what I think I'd do. It's hard to know what you're trying to do without seeing what your input tables look like and what your expected output should be. (See [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info on improving your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved the problem. The problem was on the read_csv() call. I set the index to dtype str, but failed to include engine='c' which resulted in the join to max out ram and eventually fail with a cryptic memory error.

Once fixed, ram usage increased only slightly, about a gig.